# Alexa Smart Home Error Response in the documentation is not clear enough

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-smart-home-skill

I am referring to the documentation of [Amazon Alexa Smart Home](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/device-apis/alexa-errorresponse.html) and I have a doubt related to the JSON body they have given.

```
{"event": {
"header": {
  "namespace": "Alexa",
  "name": "ErrorResponse",
  "messageId": "abc-123-def-456",
  "correlationToken": "dFMb0z+PgpgdDmluhJ1LddFvSqZ/jCc8ptlAKulUj90jSqg==",
  "payloadVersion": "3"
},
"endpoint":{
    "endpointId":"appliance-001"
},
"payload": {
  "type": "ENDPOINT_UNREACHABLE",
  "message": "Unable to reach endpoint 12345 because it appears to be offline"
}}}
```

Is this the directive from the Alexa or is this the event I need to send in the response.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `ErrorResponse`  event that you have to send to Alexa whenever an error occurs while processing a control or query directive.

The payload of an `ErrorResponse` event must specify a `type` and a `message`.

1. **type**: This indicates the kind of error that has occurred. Alexa uses this attribute to respond to the customer appropriately.
2. **message**: String that provides more information about the error for logging purposes.

`ENDPOINT_UNREACHABLE` error type indicates that the target endpoint is currently unreachable or offline.